# issue with for loop in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tk-toolkit

so im working on a small project in and im trying to get input from the user
using the entry widget and then comparing and seeing if any of the words in the input matches one or more of the words inside a list , for some reason it dosent work and the program dosent read and trying to match and instad jumps straight into showing the lable that it shouldve print only if one of the words matches :

```
e = Entry(window, width=40, borderwidth=3, font='Arial 20')
e.place(rely=0.2, relx=0.24)
r1 = Label(window, text="good", font='Arial 20')

def s_command():
    x = ["egg","milk","rice","salt"]
    s_input = e.get().split(" ")
    for s_input in x:
        r1.pack()

S_button = Button(window, text="Search", font='Arial 22', width=8, command=s_command)
S_button.place(rely=0.25, relx=0.4)
```

Comment: I do not clearly understand what you are doing. Are you entering a set of number and check if ANY of it matches the given list? Then your `for` is wrong.

Comment: the numbers are strings , i want to cheack if any of the strings inside the list are in the e.get()

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code, and read the article about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: So will `e.get()` be a set of numbers? Like "1 2 3" or just "1"

Comment: i changed the list now to strings no numbers e.get() will be whatever the user type and i want to check if any of what he typed are inside the list and if its true then i want it to print the label

Comment: Yes I understood that, I want to confirm if the user can only enter 1 or if they can enter any amount of items in a single input

Comment: they enter any amount of items in a single input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a working (if a bit pared down) example of what I think you're after

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
e = tk.Entry(window)
e.pack()

search_val = tk.StringVar()

# this label updates whenever search_val is set
lbl = tk.Label(window, textvariable=search_val)
lbl.pack()


def cmd():
    x = ['egg', 'milk', 'rice', 'salt']
    usr_in = e.get().split(' ')
    matches = ''
    for value in x:
        if value in usr_in:
            matches += value + ' '  # append all matches found in 'x'
    # update the label if there's a match from the list 'x'
    search_val.set(matches)


btn = tk.Button(window, text='Search', command=cmd)
btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here one approach is, you can use a nested loop, because you need to be checking if the user enters more than an item and if any of the items exists in the list.

```
def s_command():
    x = ["egg","milk","rice","salt"]
    s_input = e.get().split(" ")

    for inp in s_input: # Go through input list
        for item in x: # Go through items list
            if inp == item: # If an input is same as item
                r1.pack() # Show the widget
                break # Stop the loop because you want to check if any item matches
            else: 
                r1.pack_forget() # Remove the label
        # Make the nested loop break the outer loop
        else:
            continue
        break
```

Next approach is to just use a single loop(as seen in JRiggles's answer) and if the item exists in list using `in`, like:

```
def s_command():
    x = ["egg", "milk", "rice", "salt"]
    s_input = e.get().split(' ')
    
    for inp in s_input:
        if inp in x:
            r1.pack()
            break
        else:
            r1.pack_forget()
```

If you had to check just one item with the list then it would be much easier:

```
def s_command():
    x = ["egg", "milk", "rice", "salt"]
    s_input = e.get() # Only single item so no need to split
    
    if s_input in x:
        r1.pack()
    else:
        r1.pack_forget()
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a nested loop since the split `s_input` and the list `x` are both iterables. We're searching for some value from the input `in` x - see my answer above.

Comment: @JRiggles Sure that is one of the approaches too, added it